# Regular maps between Fréchet manifolds and pullbacks

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, frechet-manifold, generalized-smooth-spaces

An oft-used example of a regular map of finite-dimensional smooth manifolds is a submersion. We have the well-known result that the pullback of a submersion exists and is a submersion. For [Fréchet manifolds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Fr%C3%A9chet%20manifold), one definition of a submersion $f\colon M\to N$ is a map such that every induced map on tangent spaces $T_m M \to T_f(m) N$ is a split map of Frechet spaces. Here surjectivity is not enough. We know that the pullback of a submersion in this sense exists and is a submersion (cf. [Hamilton's paper "The inverse function theorem of Nash and Moser"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-7/issue-1/The-inverse-function-theorem-of-Nash-and-Moser/bams/1183549049.full)). So we could define a surjective regular map between Fréchet manifolds as being a submersion in this sense. My first question is then:

> What is the full definition of a smooth, regular map of Fréchet spaces?

‘Maximal rank’ on each tangent space is not enough, as we have seen.

But there are two things flowing on from this which I don't quite get. One is that, considering Fréchet manifolds as [diffeological spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diffeological%20space), there is another concept that is used, namely being a *subduction* (e.g. [Thomas Nikolaus's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48567/advantages-of-diffeological-spaces-over-general-sheaves/49242#49242) to [Advantages of Diffeological Spaces over General Sheaves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48567/advantages-of-diffeological-spaces-over-general-sheaves)), which is something like ‘is a submersion on each plot’. Now the pullback of a map of Fréchet manifolds which is a subduction is not guaranteed to be a Fréchet manifold. If it was I would be very happy.

> Can we say anything about whether the pullback diffeological space is a Fréchet manifold?

The second thing is that really in the case of constructing pullbacks of smooth manifolds, all we need is [transversality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transversal%20maps) of a pair of smooth maps with common codomain. At the Wikipedia page on [transversality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics)), versions for Banach spaces are mentioned, but no details, and clearly the step from Banach to Fréchet spaces is another step removed.

> What is the correct definition of transversal maps of Fréchet manifolds, and what is the statement about existence of pullbacks of transversal maps?

Comment: I found this http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ24_01%2FS0004972700007425a.pdf&code=f124eeb949e472f66dc05fe2f918880a for a general definition of transversality, but the paper is very opaque, and doesn't look, after a skim, that it will have what I need.

Comment: David, the link in your comment doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The paper is 'Manifolds of smooth maps II: transversality' by Truong Cong Nghe. This link to the abstract page should work: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=4761084

Comment: DOI for @‍DavidRoberts's [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98160/regular-maps-between-frechet-manifolds-and-pullbacks#comment251872_98160):  [Truong Công Nghê - Manifolds of smooth maps II: transversality](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0004972700007425).

Comment: Even worse: the definition in the question is wrong!