# Why is category theory the preferred language of advanced algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

It's pretty easy to see how category theory could be **applied** in the case of abstract algebra, but doing so doesn't seem particularly useful, at the very least, for purposes of the stuff that one finds close to undergraduate abstract algebra.

So, how exactly does category theory become more relevant as a tool, and perhaps even a necessity, for formulating mathematical facts when we go into algebraic geometry?

Comment: I would even argue that a lot of abstract algebra  becomes cleaner and more conceptual when viewed through the lens of category theory. That we don't teach it that way is of course a reasonable compromise: No one should learn about abelian categories before they learn about vector spaces, for example.

Comment: Another question one might ask is : why does sheaf theory became an important tool in algebraic geometry from the mid 50's on ? Is this an unrelated question ?

Comment: I am far from being an expert in algebraic geometry, but from my understanding here is roughly what happened : category theory was formalised in the mid 40's in order to capture some common features in homology and cohomology in the context of algebraic topology. Then, the use of it in algebraic geometry relies on at least two (maybe more) discoveries by Grothendieck and his student Verdier. One of them is that, surpisingly, the category of sheafs of sets on a topological space (and more generally on a site) has some good properties (I let the algebraic geometers explains which ones)

Comment: And, secondly, the discovery of the formalism of  derived categories, which allows one to study more extensively the cohomology of algebraic varieties. I let the algebraic geometers correct me if I am wrong, and/or add more reasons for which category theory lies at the heart of algebraic geometry since Grothendieck's era.

Comment: Rather than Close this Question, how about giving people like @Spuire the opportunity to explain their subject to the wider community?

Comment: Category theory is extremely useful in algebraic geometry, since it clarifies old notions such as moduli spaces, and suggests new concepts such as sheaves over sites and stacks. Nevertheless, I'm not sure it's the *preferred language* of AG.

Comment: @SBrian. I have been arguing similar things ever since MO started. But this request is not just for the benefit of undergrads but also grad students and professionals in algebraic geometry and many other disciplines. Stupid thing is that I have to wait for this Question to be Closed before the system lets me vote to Reopen it.

Comment: I think this question is based on a misconception.  There is nothing special about algebraic geometry.  Category theory is a useful language in almost any algebraic setting, and pretty much anyone that works in algebra uses it to at least some extent.  I don't think that algebraic geometry is even the area that uses it the most (that would probably be algebraic topology and homological algebra).  There are also important subareas of algebraic geometry that make only incidental use of category theory (e.g., look through Griffiths & Harris).

Comment: (I also think that the tendentious armchair psychology ("...rather it be seen as witchcraft, perhaps in efforts to bolster the image of their own intelligence") is totally inappropriate.)

Comment: @Andy Putman : I am not quite sure you're right when you say "There is nothing special about algebraic geometry [and category theory]". For instance, does algebraic topology make  use of the notion of topos as does algebraic geometry (refering to Grothendieck's own words in Recoltes et Semailles, it should.. but this was written in the mid 80's, so it might be that meanwhile things have changed) ? Is there an algebraic geometer in the room to confirm my feeling ? I agree with you about the strange comment of S Brian on witchcraft.

Comment: @huurd: Topos theory plays a pretty marginal role in mainstream algebraic geometry.  I suspect that more algebraic topologists care about it than algebraic geometers.

Comment: @Andy Putman : a marginal role ? would you say the same for etale cohomology ? what would etale cohomology be like without the notion of a topos ?

Comment: @AndyPutman: as a categorist, I agree that there's nothing special about algebraic geometry --- aside from the enormous influence that Grothendieck had in an early stage of the development of my subject. There should be parallel Questions with other subjects substituted for AG, each of which deserves a good Answer, all for the Education of the Youth.

Comment: @huurd: You don’t need the massive baggage of topoi to set up etale cohomology.  For instance, this standard source lists them in the index once to point to where he explains that they won’t be used: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf

Comment: @PaulTaylor: I suspect that like this one, such questions would be quickly closed.

Comment: This really is not an "opinion-based" question, although it might be borderline "research-level." But isn't the standard here supposed to be analogous to a colleague wandering into your office to ask something? I'll bet a lot of colleagues have had similar questions about why algebraic geometry is so heavy on category theory.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: But can this kind of question really be answered in a reasonable way?  I think the answer is really kind of boring: category theory is a useful and expressive language for expressing algebraic concepts, so it is used in basically all algebraic fields.  I really don’t think algebraic geometry is any more category-theory intensive than eg representation theory, homological algebra, algebraic topology, etc.

Comment: @SBrian, try to clarify your *question*, and particularly the last sentence.

Comment: @huurd: No, I don’t think that at all.  I don’t think those people actually exist.  Everyone that is at all connected to algebraic geometry (including me) acknowledges their massive debt to Grothendieck’s work.  You shouldn’t take the more paranoid parts of R&S seriously as an accurate account of the world.  Here for instance is an account by one of the people Grothendieck slanders: https://www.jmilne.org/math/Documents/GrothendieckandMe.html

Comment: @ Andy Putman : it turns out that I have been reading those parts of RetS during the last few weeks, and I was precisely wondering to what extent the words of Grothendieck reflect the reality. It's great to hear your opinion about that, but do you think those "paranoid" parts are entirely false, or is there a bit of truth in it ? For example, the unwanted lonliness of Z Mebkhout during a bunch of years while he was discovering important things in the late 70's ?

Comment: @AndyPutman I'm not sure that it's true that category theory is used more or less the same amount in all algebraic fields. For example, based on my (admittedly superficial) understanding of the classification of finite simple groups, I don't think that it makes heavy use of category theory. In my own field of algebraic combinatorics, category theory does not get used much even in combinatorial representation theory. (Species are category-theoretic but it's a relatively specialized subfield.) But in algebraic geometry, many important *definitions* require category theory to even state.

Comment: @AndyPutman, aren't psychologists / psychiatrists typically ensconced in armchairs when practicing their professions?

Comment: I'd like to see a possible Toynbee-ish approach. For example, the development of group theory was closely intertwined with the challenge of solving quartic, quintic, and higher-order equations and then with understanding conservation theorems / invariants in mathematical physics; the development of operational calculus, with the challenges of electric circuit theory (and practice); Lie theory, with the challenges of the mathematical underpinnings of quantum theory; and so on. The development of category theory has been intertwined with the challenge(s) of understanding . . . (?).

Comment: @TomCopeland. (I like the quotations on your profile page.) "category theory has been intertwined with the challenge(s) of understanding . . ."  many, many things, because it is an *attitude* to doing mathematics, not a particular body of it.  Try reading the abstracts on the recent [international conference](http://sites.uclouvain.be/ct2023/).

Comment: @TomCopeland Lie theory was originally motivated in large part by trying to replicate the success of Galois theory in the context of differential equations. As for category theory, its initial development was intertwined with the challenges of understanding algebraic topology, and much of the category theory in algebraic geometry stems from the application of the ideas of algebraic topology to algebraic geometry.

Comment: @Timothy Chow : is there a link between the use of Lie groups you just mentioned for differential equations, and the theory of differentially closed fields ?     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentially_closed_field

Comment: @huurd I'm not aware of such a link. My go-to reference for this topic is Olver's book *Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations*.

Comment: @huurd See https://inference-review.com/article/a-truncated-manuscript for Grothendieck's later views on Z Mebkhout.

Comment: @Justin Hilburn : in this later version it is not clear what Grothendieck eventually thought about the situation of Z Mebkhout "I was contacted by Pierre Schapira, and then by Christian Houzel, to point out some glaring inaccuracies in the version of events presented in Récoltes et semailles. The situation was clarified considerably during correspondence with both of them. It now appears to me that in the “[Zoghman] Mebkhout version” (which was not lacking in internal consistency) the true, the tendentious and the downright false are inextricably mixed"

Comment: @timothyChow, matrix theory received a real shot in the arm with the advent of QM. This rising to an occasion, this synergy informs both subjects. Knowing with whom the developers are arguing also informs--the dialectic. The historical tension between a traditional diff op approach and a more purely grp theoretic one is discussed by Bonolis in "From the Rise of the Group Concept to the Stormy Onset of Group Theory in the New Quantum Mechanics. A saga of the invariant characterization of physical objects, events and theories".

Answer (score 18):

I assume you understand how the basic language of category theory (morphisms, functors, natural transformation) is very *convenient* in many areas of mathematics, and that your question is more about why category theory seems to be particularly *indispensable* when it comes to modern algebraic geometry. For example, sheaves are often defined in introductory books on *differential* geometry without referring to category theory, and even Ext and Tor can be defined and studied with a bare minimum of categorical language.  At what point in algebraic geometry does category theory become more than just a convenience?

I'd nominate the notion of a [Grothendieck topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology) as one of the simplest concepts that is indispensable to modern algebraic geometry and that one cannot reasonably define without  category theory.  As others have noted, from an early stage, it seemed that the Weil conjectures were begging to be proved via cohomological techniques.  But conventional topology was not up to the task of defining a suitable cohomology theory, and hence Grothendieck came up with the notion of a Grothendieck topology (and related concepts).

Since then, of course, increasingly sophisticated applications of category theory have entered algebraic geometry, but I think this is still a good example of a basic concept that requires more than a superficial use of categorical language.

Answer (score 11):

I feel that the question gives a slightly false impression. Since it has been reopened, let me explain my attitude, which I expect is not atypical among algebraic geometers. When I teach algebraic geometry, I usually spend part of a lecture discussing some basic category theory: categories, functors, limits, but not much more than that. (And most students are already familiar with this stuff from their algebra class.) So where does this come up?

1. In scheme theory (or in the study of varieties, for that matter), the (fibre) product is not the naive product of topological spaces, it's the categorical one. To prove existence it is necessary to know that the category of affine schemes and commutative rings are anti-equivalent. Similarly, group schemes are not groups in the usual sense, but are groups in the category of schemes.
2. When discussing operations on sheaves, it's good to know that $f^*$ is not the inverse of $f_*$ but the left adjoint. Also exactness properties  of these operations are important, especially it comes time to discussing sheaf cohomology.
3. If I have time (but I usually don't), I might discuss what some moduli spaces are in terms of the functors they represent. So Yoneda's lemma is needed here.

Some parts of algebraic geometry (e.g. stacks, derived stuff)  certainly use a lot more category theory and than what I described. But for much of it, a middling amount is enough.

Answer (score 10):

$\quad$It is not difficult to show how category theory works on algebraic geometry by giving some examples, such as “the category of affine varieties is equivalent to the category of finitely generated k-algebras” somehow explains why algebraic geometry is based on commutative algebra; “maxSpec is not functorial, but Spec is” implies the motivation for the definition affine $n$-space and so on.
$\quad$Besides, I think there is another perfect way to make this problem understood——to study about Grothendieck.

---

$\quad$Why Grothendieck’s theory succeeded? He himself attributed some of the reasons to the development of category theory. In fact, Serre’s discussion on coherent sheaf in FAC was very successful at first, but he mainly used the tools of etale space. This leads to some complicated and unclear proofs. However, Grothendieck in his EGA made clear that he won’t use etale space, but the language of category theory. This move make it possible to just talk about presheaf without etale space and sheaf, meanwhile contributing to some new discoveries in sheaf theory.
$\quad$And all this is for solving Weil Conjecture, Serre told Grothendieck that Weil Conjecture can be solved by establishing a cohomology theory on Weil’s “space”, in which Lefschetz Fixed Point holds. But the properties of Weil’s space is too bad to build a cohomology theory because it doesn’t has separation property.
$\quad$After a period of time, people came to understand the essence of sheaf cohomology and Cech cohomology by the tools from homological algebra. Then something like Grothendieck topology, even topos theory was invented by Grothendieck. And all this work are closely related to homology, whose foundation is totally category theory.

Comment: what's a FAC..?

Comment: @SBrian Faisceaux Algebriques Coherents by Serre

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The word "\'{e}tal\'{e}" is the past participle of the French verb "\'{e}taler" = "to spread out", rather than the French adjective "\'{e}tale" = "calm, slack".  So the "\'{e}space \'{e}tal\'{e}" is really quite different than "\'{e}tale space".

Comment: @JasonStarr Oh, thank you for your correction, I haven’t notice that.

Comment: Isn't the foundation of category theory in homological algebra, rather than *vice versa*?  Surely homological algebra predated category theory (in a sense explicitly recognised as such).

Comment: @LSpice Yes, actually Grothendieck’s work on homology influenced category theory much. For “foundations” I mean the original category theory before Grothendieck.

Comment: @JasonStarr, or, more clearly using the Compose key on my British keyboard, The word étalé is the past participle of the French verb étaler = to spread out, rather than the adjective étale = stable (that [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9tale) doesn't know).

Comment: @JasonStarr: The adjective “étale” in “étale space” is the same as “étale” in “étale map”, which is quite natural since the map from the étale space to the base space is indeed an étale map.  There is no reason why “étale space” must be a literal translation of “espace étalé”.  Also, the spelling “étale space” is far more common in the published literature (in English) than anything containing “étalé”; there any many books using “étale space”, but I am aware of only one book (Wells) using “étalé space”.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov  Maybe I misunderstood what the poster meant, but I assume that was an English translation of "\'{e}space \'{e}tal\'{e}", as in Serre.  That is what I was referring to.  Perhaps you mean something other than this.

Comment: @JasonStarr: It is the same notion, but I have not seen any claims (in the answer itself or anywhere in the published literature) that “étale space” is meant to be a literal translation of “espace étalé”.

Comment: @JasonStarr I guess that the difference between étalé and étale is linguistic pedantry. There is no essential mathematical difference: Let $X$ be a topological space. Then there is an equivalence between sheaves over $X$ and étale spaces over $X$ (a map is called *étale* if it is a local homeomorphism). Given a sheaf on $X$, the so-called "espace étalé" is simply the étale space associated to that sheaf.

Comment: @Z.M If you think the difference between the correct translation and an incorrect translation is linguistic pedantry, I am fine with that.  The etale topos was introduced after the “space” of a sheaf was introduced.